# Enable and disable command button when picture box is empty or filled

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am doing project on data add and update. The below code will enable the command button only if all the text fields are filled and an image is uploaded from file, but the command button is enabling even if the image is empty in picture box. Please help me with enabling and disabling the command button when the image is filled and emptied.

```
Private Sub txtfields_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtpassword.TextChanged
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtid.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtname.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtusername.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtpassword.Text) AndAlso picuser.Image Is Nothing Then
        btnadd.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain what this code does or doesn't do.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written `AndAlso picuser.Image Is Nothing Then` which means that that "if the image is nothing"

I suggest you to change that part to:

```
AndAlso picuser.Image is nothing = false then
```

Hope this helps! 
:)

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to mark the answer as helpful :)